# How to stop grub from messing with my EFI partition?

Tags: linux-mint, grub2, uefi

I'm dual booting Windows 8.1 and Linux Mint. I decided to install the Linux Mint OS (Rebecca) onto an EXTERNAL HDD.

So what I did was click "Something Else" during installation and I created 3 partitions on the External HDD.

- 1. EFI Partition
- 2. Swap Partition
- 3. Root "/" Partition

Note: There's no more free space after that. The above 3 partitions took all of it (as intended).

Then at the very bottom, I chose to install the bootloader to /dev/ssd instead of /dev/sda.

When I was finished installing mint and I booted into windows, I ran the following batch file as Administrator:

```
@echo off
mountvol b: /s
taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe
start explorer.exe
start explorer.exe
```

Then I went to my Windows (Internal HDD) EFI partition.. And there it is! GRUB is installed in the EFI folder as "Ubuntu":

[image]
And when I check my BIOS, there's 2 new options to boot "Ubuntu". I don't want this. I want to have everyone only on the external drive (EFI partition and all). It has to be possible. I did it with my hackintosh (Clover EFI) but can't seem to figure out how to do it with GRUB..

No matter what I do, it keeps messing with my internal MBR and installing to the internal EFI partition. Would be even better if I can just boot it without grub.

Any ideas?

Comment: Go read [EFI bootloader principles](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html), grab `efibootmgr` and carefully remove the extra option from firmware's NVRAM.  You might also like `refind` as the boot manager.